# Why Is Intellij Suggesting I Make A Private Field Private in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, java-17

Why is Intellij suggesting I make a private field private? Am I not understanding this correctly or is it just a bug? I have posted a picture of the error and the decompiled class below. Is this something I should heed or ignore?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a suggestion about the property, not the field. In Java side a property is essentially a field and its accessor methods.

If you changed `val s` to `private val s`, the decompiled class would have `private` visibility for the `getS()` accessor rather than `public`.